# StringTemplate Formatting last item in a list

Tags: java, string, stringtemplate

I am generating source using StringTemplate, I need to render a list of statements I want all but last to be separated with a ";\n" but format last one to be wrapped in a "return item;\n"
can i achieve this in the template or do i have to do some preprocessing manually?

```
$call.stmts:{$it$;} ;separator="\n"$
```

Currently I am using the above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the trunc() function to get everything in the list but the last element, and the last() method to get the last element, as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130831014000/http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet)